# MySQL throws error while secure_installation

Tags: mysql

I am installing MySQL using link: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7

But after installing step 3 for secure_installation `sudo mysql_secure_installation`.

It shows password to enter, and when I enter password or leave it blank, it shows Error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. MySql is not SQL Server.

Comment: And software installation has nothing to do with the SQL language.

Comment: i have not choosen software language i have choosed option 'OTHERS'